# D3 ticks() does not return value if provided scale has only 1 result

Tags: d3.js

I have an x-axis that displays the days that my data occurs on. The data is dynamic and sometimes I have data for only 1 day, 2 days, n days, etc.

Here is my code for displaying the days on the x-axis:

```
chart.x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, chart.w]);

chart.xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(chart.x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(d3.time.day)                                 // --- TODO : this is not showing the current day, for some reason...
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%b %-d %p"));
```

If my data is spread on 2 days (ex: Tuesday, Wednesday), this will only display a tick for the second day (Wednesday), ie. when the day "changes" from one to another.
I want to also display a tick for the first day (Tuesday).
Even if there is only data on 1 day, I still want to display a tick for it.

Thanks you guys,

Answer (score 2):

To extend the domain so that the scale starts and ends at a tick mark you use the `.nice()` method, as @meetamit suggested -- but "nicing" only works if you call that method *after* you set the domain, so that's why you might not have noticed any change.  The API doesn't really make that clear, although since the method alters the domain I suppose it makes sense that changing the domain later would over-ride the effect of a previous `nice()` call.

Also, be sure to use the [time-scale version of the method](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales#wiki-nice): `.nice(d3.time.day)` to get a domain rounded off to the nearest day as opposed to just the nearest hour.

Here's a fiddle:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/4rGQq/

The key code is simply:

```
xScale.domain(d3.extent(d)) 
      //d3.extent() returns max and min of array, which become the basic domain
      .nice(d3.time.day);  
      //nice() extends the domain to nearest start/end of a day
```

Compare what happens if you comment out the `.nice()` call after setting the domain, even with the other `.nice()` call during initialization of the scale.  Also compare what happens if you don't specify the day-interval as a parameter to the nice method.

Comment: Thanks so much for all these rich examples! Learned a lot from them.
This and meetamit's answers are making me understand what I really need finally, which is not to play with scales, domains, etc, but rather only to retrieve the first day in the data and display it on the graph somehow. For now, I have another x-axis with hour marks and I would like to attach this day label to the left-most hour mark (![see this image](http://i44.tinypic.com/awz3mq.jpg). This is an entirely different question now, though.

Comment: Sounds sensible -- it avoids stretching out your domain by up to 23 hours on either side just to reach the next start-of-day tick mark.  To get you started, once you've created your hour-axis, you can select the first tick mark group using `xAxisGroup.select("g.tick:first-of-type")` (where xAxisGroup is a d3 selection of the group in which you drew the axis).  Once you've got the tick-group selection, you can access the timestamp value it's associated with using `.datum()` and access it's position within the xAxisGroup using `.style("transform")`, which will return a translate statement.

Comment: P.S.  Some other possible approaches to work with:  http://fiddle.jshell.net/4rGQq/3/  http://fiddle.jshell.net/4rGQq/4/

Comment: Awesome! This givens me all the ammunition I need. Thanks so much,

Answer (score 1):

Can you show how `chart.x` is set up? Hard to tell without seeing it, but you may be able to fix it by calling `chart.x.nice()` (see [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales#wiki-nice)).

Otherwise, seems like you'll need to manually check the extents of its domain, and adjust them in the case of single day.

**Clarification**

Your code shows how you call `range()` but not how you call `domain()`, which is the important one.

It seems to me to me that if do

```
var domain = chart.x.domain()
console.log domain[0] == domain[1]
```

you'll see `true` getting logged whenever the data is for only one day. If so, it means you're dealing with a single point in time rather than a time range. In that case, you'll need to adjust the domain to be a longer range.

Really hard to know without even seeing an image of what you're working on.

Comment: I added chart.x's definition in the post. There's nothing special about it though.
I don't understand what you mean in your second sentence. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: And I checked the nice() function out. It's great but won't change the fact that `tick(d3.time.day)` doesn't return the current day.

Comment: @jcnesci I added some more explanation

Comment: `nice()` should work, but has its complications that were too much to explain in a comment so I added another answer (with fiddle).

Comment: ![Here's an image](http://i44.tinypic.com/awz3mq.png). I'm trying to get the ticks() to return the current day so I can display it below the left-most tickmark of my hour ticks (which is a another separate label axis). Just like the red text in the image.

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand domains and nicing more, by the way, very appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

`.ticks()` should be used to set the number of ticks you'd like to have on your axis, not the kind of data that should be in them. So try to set it like `.ticks(3)` and it should set a couple of ticks.
From the wiki:
***.ticks([count])***
Returns approximately count representative values from the scale's input domain. If count is not specified, it defaults to 10. The returned tick values are uniformly spaced, have human-readable values (such as multiples of powers of 10), and are guaranteed to be within the extent of the input domain. Ticks are often used to display reference lines, or tick marks, in conjunction with the visualized data. The specified count is only a hint; the scale may return more or fewer values depending on the input domain.

Comment: What I'm already using does work, however it only displays days when there are at least 2 (just to clarify). I believe it's an alternative way of using .ticks() since I picked it up from other tutorials, etc. Your method works of course, but it does not adapt to the number of days in my data. If I have 1 day in my data, I want 1 tick; 2 days, 2 ticks; 3 days, 3 ticks; etc.
Thanks though!

Comment: the fact is that you can't really control the number of ticks, as the last few line says: The specified count is only a hint; the scale may return more or fewer values depending on the input domain.
Maybe you can setup the .tick() with a function to hide the ticks that do not represent your data (but then you'll have an uneven white space in your axis)

Comment: also if you could set up a jsfiddle maybe we could help you better

Comment: thanks for the comment. A JSfiddle is a good idea but Im building my chart with [MISO d3.chart](http://misoproject.com/d3-chart/) so it's complicated to port back to a normal D3 chart in a fiddle.

Comment: Just to clarify, it's not that I have ticks that don't represent my data, it's only that I am missing a tick for the current day, which happens equally if I only have one day (no ticks are shown) or if I have 2 days (only a tick for the 2nd day is shown). It weird to me that it's so hard to force it to show a tick for the current day.

Comment: Actually, the usage of `.ticks(d3.time.day)` is perfectly valid when using a [time scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales#wiki-ticks), and will in general give the results @jcnesci wants.