# D3 - How to display year at the beginning and end of the date range in X axis?

Tags: d3.js

Currently I am displaying dates at X axis like this:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(d3.time.day, 1)
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%a %d"));
```

So my question is: There is a way to add the year at the beginning and end of the date range in axis?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. Do you want special labels at the start/end of the axis, or ticks only every month?

Comment: Add special labels at the start/end of the axis. Those can be the month or the year. Thanks!

Comment: In general, the only reliable way to do this is to set the tick values explicitly using [`.tickValues()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-tickValues).

Comment: Hi prozco.  Look at the comments to the first answer to this question, it should get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008922/  The relevant fiddles are   http://fiddle.jshell.net/4rGQq/3 and http://fiddle.jshell.net/4rGQq/4

Comment: Great.  If you could, add a short code snippet as an answer, and mark it accepted, so this doesn't show up as an unanswered question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @AmeliaBR

```
var dateFormat = d3.time.format("%b %Y");
d3.selectAll("g.tick:first-of-type")
    .append("text")
    .classed("dateTick", true)
    .attr("dy", "5em")
    .attr("class", "start-date")
    .text(function(d){return dateFormat(d);});
```