# d3 axis is not showing any values if there is only 1 value in the domain

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using values from a drop down list to generate my parallel coordinate graph. The axis value does not show if the domain for it has only 1 value.

```
Data{
  Fruit X Y
  Apple 1 2
  Orange 2 3
}
```

Eg: I am selecting Apple in the drop-down, the axis for X and Y are shown but the Fruit axis is lost, though when i load the graph with all values, fruit axis shows. It is similar to this question but putting nice() is not working in my case since mine is an ordinal scale

[D3 ticks() does not return value if provided scale has only 1 result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008922/d3-ticks-does-not-return-value-if-provided-scale-has-only-1-result)

Answer (score 0):

I could fix it. There was a condition which prevented the axis from showing up if there are less than 2 values. The statement which needed the update:

if (__.types[p] == "string" && (uniques > 60 || uniques < 2))

I changed it to:

if (__.types[p] == "string" && (uniques > 60 || uniques < 1))